# Migrating Outlook 2007 local settings across Windows XP machines

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-office-2007

Outlook 2007 (and 2003) stores many settings including email signatures locally, and users that move frequently from machine to machine have to spend time setting all these up.

Office 2003 included a utility, called the "Microsoft Office 2003 Save My Settings Wizard", which was useful in migrating these settings, and it was usable by users.

I am aware of a tool on Windows Vista called "Windows Easy Transfer" to migrate user settings.

Is there a utility like this for Office 2007 running on Windows XP that we can make available to our users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start button 
-> All Programs
-> Accessories 
-> System Tools 
-> File and Settings Transfer Wizard

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason that you don't just enable [roaming profiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roaming_user_profile) for these users?  That will get all the users settings, and not just Outlook.

- [Configuring Roaming User Profiles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738596.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go with roaming profiles, check out the User State Migration Tool (USMT) at microsoft's website. From what I understand it will do exectly what you need, and it's not too hard to make a nice little bat-file that pulls the settings you want.